# How to parse a JSON object from an external file in React using .map() in ES6 and a loop?

Tags: json, reactjs, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a JSON object which is in an external file using React, and display its content inside a loop containing HTML. The goal is to display all that into a JQuery Slider (Slick).

I think I succeeded in importing the JSON, but I can't display it. Most of the results I find on the internet are in ES5 also.

Here is my slider.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import slidesData from './slides.json';

export class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            slides: slidesData,
        }
    }

    render() {
        const list = this.state.slides.map(d => <div className="classTest">ID HERE {slidesData.id} - DESCRIPTION HERE {slidesData.desc}</div>);
        return (
            <div className="carousel">
                <div className="data">
                    <div>list before {list} list after</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

slides.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "desc": "text desc 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "desc": "text desc 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "desc": "text desc 3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "desc": "text desc 4"
    }
]
```

Result in the browser:

```
list before
ID HERE - DESCRIPTION HERE
ID HERE - DESCRIPTION HERE
ID HERE - DESCRIPTION HERE
ID HERE - DESCRIPTION HERE
list after
```

The files are in the same folder.
So the `{list}` is displayed 4 times (like the items it contains) but it doesn't display the content. What am I missing?

And then, I would like to repeat each `<div className="data">` with a `for` loop displaying every time the JSON has content but until I find why the json is not getting displayed properly I don't want to try more complicated code.

Thanks =)

Comment: `this.state.slides.map(d => <div className="classTest">ID HERE {d.id} - DESCRIPTION HERE {d.desc}</div>);`

Comment: There is React port of Slick slider, you can use that. (it's better not to use jQuery in your react app). Have a look at this 
https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong object in your `.map()`. You should access `d` instead of `slidesData`:

```
 render() {
        const list = this.state.slides.map((d, index) => <div className="classTest" key={index}>ID HERE {d.id} - DESCRIPTION HERE {d.desc}</div>); //changed
        return (
            <div className="carousel">
                <div className="data">
                    <div>list before {list} list after</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**EDIT**

You should also provide a `key` to your tags within the `.map()`. I edited my original answer.

Comment: This works! I thought I did that and it didn't work... Well, getting used to webpack server refresh. If I want to learn how to iterate a loop on the `<div className="data">`, should I ask it here or in a new topic? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, ask another question for that

Comment: It's going to be hard. I got -1 on this question and now I'm banned "You have reached your question limit". I really tried my best but I still can't get how stackoverflow is working. I try quoting, putting into code, using proper words, questions, looking into hundreds of topics for weeks before asking... I'm depressed now. Never happened to me before on the whole internet for 15 years now.

Comment: I can see your frustration. If you really need help, let me know (discord, skype, ...)

Comment: Yes, I think I need help. I don't see any way to get out of this situation, by editing or whatever. And I really don't understand my ban. Can I contact you privately?

Comment: What communication tools do you use? In discord: Nocebo#5171

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153103/discussion-between-nocebo-and-lightben).

Comment: I don't know Discord. I mostly use Allo/WhatsApp or email. I also have Skype. Tell me what is better

Comment: I send you a chat invite. If you can't chat yet, please get discord. There are also `react`-channels

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it your map is referencing 'd', but you're trying to access via {slidesData.id}

try:

```
const list = this.state.slides.map(d => return (<div 
className="classTest">ID HERE `${d.id}` - DESCRIPTION HERE `${d.desc}`</div>));
```